# While I click one listview item and change its background , why it is not working?

Tags: android, android-listview

Following is my source code,

I also tried `isPressed` , `isClicked` , but it still doesn't work.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        // This a new view we inflate the new layout
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_item_layout, parent, false);
    }
    MyItem myItem = getItem(position);


    TextView direction = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.direction);
    direction.setText(myItem .getDirection());

    if(convertView.isSelected()){
        convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_select_bar);
        setTextColor(convertView, textIDs , R.color.white);
    }else{
        convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.light_white);
        setTextColor(convertView, textIDs , R.color.black);
    }

    return convertView;
}
```

Actually , if I remove the convertView check block, I just need to register an onItemClickListener onto the listview... but if I do this , seems makes getView method meaningless. I am so struggled with this issue.

Comment: what is setTextColor method and did you try calling invalidate method ?

Comment: I try "convertView.setOnClickListener" is working, but other items that I haven't clickd also change their background. A regular pattern appears. Ex: items in index 0 , 9 , 18 were also affected.

Comment: This is because your were re-using the convertView, Just remove the code `convertView == null` and inflate for each convertView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First , I appreciate that Sam gave me such a useful tip.
Following is my resolve procedure.

Write a selector file and below is its content. then put this list_background.xml into drawable folder

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/list_select_bar" android:state_pressed="true"/><!--pressed -->
<item android:drawable="@color/light_white"/><!-- default --></selector>
```

then in your item layout xml , using list_background like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

...
    android:background="@drawable/list_background"
   ...
    >

That's it. No click listener or other method invoked in the source code.

Answer (score 0):

`getView` is called only while rendering the list view. Its is not called when an item is selected or clicked.

Probably what u need is to use `convertView.setOnFocusChangeListener`

Answer (score 0):

`getView()` creates (or re-creates) a View that wasn't visible. So a new view like this cannot be selected, pressed or clicked.

I believe you want a [Color State Selector](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html).

---

(From the link above)
XML file saved at `res/color/button_text.xml`:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
          android:color="#ffff0000"/> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:state_focused="true"
          android:color="#ff0000ff"/> <!-- focused -->
    <item android:color="#ff000000"/> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

This layout XML will apply the color list to a View:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_text"
    android:textColor="@color/button_text" />
```

Or you can use a similar method with a [ListView State Selector](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList) for ListViews, GridViews, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want the background color to change only when you've got your finger down on the row and change back when you let go? To do this, just add on OnTouchListener to your row item.

```
convertView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_select_bar);
        } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP 
                || event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) {
            convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.light_white);
        }
        return false;
    }
);
```

Comment: Hi JRod, your suggestion worked...

but I can not scroll my listview now.

Comment: Apologies, I forgot to add the return value (I've edited the answer). What are you returning, true or false? If you return true, the OnTouchListener will consume the event, which may be preventing your list view from scrolling. Just return false, and the touch event will be passed on.

Comment: I have added return false as your answer did. Listview is still sticked, I guess something locked the listview.

Comment: Actually I can change the background color now, but I was struggle with why other items are affected , either.
A regular pattern appears. Ex: items in index 0 , 9 , 18 were also affected ,even I just click index 1.

Comment: That happens because convertView is reused rather than allocating n instances of the same view. If you're trying to select rows (rather than just highlight on touch), try recording that on the model (eg, "MyItem") and checking it in getView() and setting it appropriately, otherwise you get behaviour as you just described.